# Shopware 6: Missing node_modules in Storefront Compilation

Tags: npm, puppeteer, chromium, shopware, shopware6

When I try to compile shopware 6 with

`./bin/build-storefront.sh`

i get an error message, that the Chromium Download could not be done.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/username/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r950341! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! [Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, realpath '/home/username/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-950341'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -22,
npm ERR!   code: 'EINVAL',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'realpath',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/username/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-950341'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/username/.npm/_logs/2022-09-14T08_03_06_847Z-debug.log
```

(I replaced the real username and shopname folders with username here.)

I checked the folder `/home/username/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/`, but it is empty.

**Should I run npm install in the shoproot?**

**Is it save, to run npm install in an advanced developed system, or will it break things?**

Sure I'll make a backup first, but I am not sure, if I can run it anyway. The shop is a staging system of a complete running shopware system with a couple of extensions and custom themes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an environment variable you can set to skip the download. Execute this before running the storefront build script.

```bash
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I added also

```
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`
```

in case you already have chrome/chromium installed.

Comment: Please use comments for this type of answers.